# bootstrap, верстка

Tags: вёрстка

Сверстал проект на Bootstrap 3, потом на браузере нажал уменьшить до 90% 
(CTR -). Понял что так красивее по крайней мере на моем ноуте на других не проверял. Ну делаю для себя главное как я вижу ето.

Подскажите как мне уменьшить размер что бы не менять все стили. есть такой способ ??

Comment: вы можете объяснить по русски что вам надо ?

Comment: если только для себя, но так пусть и будет. браузер запоминает настройки масштаба для сайта :) в бутстрапе стили не наследуются друг от друга, так что придется менять все вручную.

Comment: Стили Bootstrap компилируются из LESS/SASS исходников. Поменяйте базовый размер шрифта, перекомпилируйте CSS и будет вам счастье.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать параметр стиля:

```
body {transform: scale(0.9)}
```